# HP ALM REST API using C# - update data in Test set

Tags: c#, asp.net, alm

Our HP ALM version is 12.20
From the reference link https://www.aneejian.com/2017/03/hp-alm-rest-api-authentication.html
I am able to authenticate user but when try for test set update or get project information from QC I am getting HTTP 404 error.

I tried even by creating the cookie but still facing the same HTTP 404.

Comment: 404 generally means you're trying to access information that is not present on the server. An authentication failure would yield 403.

Comment: @O.Jones But information is there we are able to login to server and check.

Comment: It's possible your REST urls are not correct.

Comment: I followed the pattern mentioned in [link](https://www.aneejian.com/2017/03/hp-alm-rest-api-authentication.html) eg: http://youralmserver:port/qcbin/rest/domains/domainName/projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding cookie to [site-session object](http://vcgcqc01:8080/qcbin/rest/site-session) able to maintain session.

```
string LWSSOCookie = AuthCookies.Substring(AuthCookies.IndexOf("LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=") + 17);
LWSSOCookie = LWSSOCookie.Substring(0, LWSSOCookie.IndexOf(";"));
createSessionRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY", LWSSOCookie){ Domain = target.Host });
```

Finally need to add the "createSessionRequest" CookieContainer to ALM get service.